# Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running? - At Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, emulation

I installed android studio and tried to run easy projects.

But I caught strange error message:

```
Waiting for device.
/usr/local/idea/android-studio/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus-4-18-xhdpi -netspeed full -netdelay none

emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is online: emulator-5554
Target device: Nexus-4-18-xhdpi [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
    local path: /home/nazar/Documents/coursera-android/Examples/HelloAndroid/out/production/HelloAndroid/HelloAndroid.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/course.examples.HelloWorld.HelloWorld
Installing course.examples.HelloWorld.HelloWorld
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/course.examples.HelloWorld.HelloWorld"
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

I couldn't figure out why this happen?

I installed sdk version and configured emulator. Any suggestions?

Here is emulator confiuration:

[image: emulator confiuration]

**Update:**

I tried to install Genymotion device and use few virtual devices, but caught:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: genymotion-nexus_4___4_4_2___api_19___768x1280-192.168.56.101:5555
Uploading file
    local path: /home/nazar/Documents/coursera-android/Examples/HelloAndroid/out/production/HelloAndroid/HelloAndroid.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/course.examples.HelloWorld.HelloWorld
Installing course.examples.HelloWorld.HelloWorld
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/course.examples.HelloWorld.HelloWorld"
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

**How to solve this error?**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524185/could-not-access-the-package-manager-is-the-system-running-while-installing-and

Comment: @pyus13 I added some details to the question. I guess it is some trouble with installation...

Comment: You can try this : First launch the emulator using AVD manager and let it start completely . Try to install application once you see the home screen and let me know if still you face the same issue ? Also try to install application from command line instead of Studio and check the results .

Comment: @pyus13 ` Also try to install application from command line instead of Studio` can you explain more?

Comment: Go to `Android SDK\platform-tools` open your cmd there and perform `adb install YOUR_APP_PATH` .Let me know your Android Studio version as well .

Comment: iS you problem resolved ? Let me know if you need any MORE clarification I will put that in answer.

Comment: @pyus13 what does this mean `YOUR_APP_PAT`?

Comment: your application full path like `adb install "D:/myapps/app.apk"` . try to install any app not specific only the app you are building.

Comment: check my answer to install apk using command line.

Comment: @pyus13  I don't think the other Stackoverflow question you linked to is related to this issue.  At least the error message is vastly different.

Comment: For me, the issue was that Genymotion had frozen. When I restarted it, install then worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First make sure you are running Android Studio version above 0.3.2 because there was some issue reported regarding the same in AS 0.3.2 . If it is not you can update it from `Help >Check for update`.

If you are already running AS above 0.3.2 :

Seems like issue is with your emulator not with Android Studio. It may happen that you are trying to install application before even the emulator started properly.

Wait till the home screen appears in the emulator before trying to install any application.

Also try to install any apk in Emulator from command line

**Steps to install**

- Go to $Android_SDK_DIR\platform-tools, right click there keeping
  shift key pressed and Chose "Open Command Window here".
- Run command `adb devices` to make sure yout emulator is running
  properly. It will show all your running emulators.
- Now if emulators are showing properly, type the command `adb install
  YOUR_FULL_APK_PATH` , YOUR_FULL_APK_PATH is of any .apk file path in
  your system.

Please update if this works fine.

Comment: here is my prompts: `nazar@nazar-desktop:/usr/local/eclipse/android-sdk/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools$ adb devices
List of devices attached ` And empty line...

Comment: Run this before adb devices  `adb kill-server` than   `adb start-server` .

Comment: Are this ok, that none device is running at this time?

Comment: no, if any emulator is running on your machine it should show the emulators list.

Comment: ya its correct now try to install any app using the command shared and let me know  its working or not ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46739/discussion-between-pyus13-and-nazar-art)

Comment: Just running adb devices will show the device as "online" way before package manager can actually be accessed.  I can shell into the device as soon as it is listed as "online".  Is there a way to check if package manager is running through the shell?

Answer (score 8):

The most common cause of this error is simple: You have to manually unlock your Android Virtual Device by swiping the “lock” icon on the screen. Security measures prevent the emulator from letting you connect the debugger before doing this.

The problem is resolved:

In Android Studio

1. Start run/debug
2. if you see the message
3. Do not closed the AVD, just click on run/debug again, the Application will be running when you unlock the application.

Answer (score 5):

The same problem but different solution, I modified my Virtual Device, I changed Memory option and Internal Storage, and it works fine.
RAM:512 , VM HEap: 192, Internal Storage=200, SD Card Size: 200 for Device Nexus 4 android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 4):

In my case this error was caused by SELinux. I got to set SELinux to permissive.

```
adb shell su 0 setenforce 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, but I found that simply killing the emulator and restarting it worked. There seems to be some sort of race condition where the emulator has not initialized before Android Studio tries to launch the apk and so you get the package error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this too, and using this ***config*** worked for me :

> Device:        Nexus One
>   Target:        Android 4.2.2 -api level 17
>   CPU/ABI:   ARM (armeabi-v7a)
>   Keyboard:  Hardware keyboard present

***Memory Options***:

> RAM:               512
>   VM Heap:           192
>   Iternal Storage:    200

***SD Card***:

> Size:200

Answer (score 1):

This Is Worked for me

1)Close Solution.

2)Close Emulator.

3)Run Emulator and Wait till it launch completely and shows Home Screen.

4)After that only Open Solution And Clean,Rebuild and Try to deploy Application.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me right now. I don't know if there is another but for me the following worked:

- Opened AVD (Android Virtual Device) Manager
- Started virtual device
- Hit the Run button again (that one at status bar)

Explanation: The problem happened because of timeout. Once device had started, the Android Studio could comunicate with him. (v 0.5.3)

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove this emulator (in the AVD)
2. Install this emulator (in the AVD) :)