# Android App is not installing in emulator or mobile

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator

I am new to android. I am doing one app in that I used older version code(4.4) which is already available as project. I imported that project as module and added dependencies in my module "app". No errors are present at compile time or run time. It showing build successful. But when I am trying to install that apk file it was showing app not installed. It was not installing either in emulator or mobile. I thought that because of version difference so I changed the older version to newer version in manifest file and build.gradle file. After that also app was not installing. Can anybody help me why I am facing this problem.I am struggling from yesterday with this issue. Please help me.. 
I will be thankful.

Comment: what is min sdk in your manifest and your android device/emulator version

Comment: have you got just one main activity in your manifest ? and this in your manifest : 
`<activity
            android:name=".MyApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`
Where my app is your first Activity

Comment: min sdk to 7 target sdk to 22.emulator 22 device version is 21. I have activites in my manifest file. Before added the code of older version it worked fine in emulator or mobile

Comment: is version code number and version name reflect the output?

Comment: And have you got any trouble in your logcat ?

Comment: If I have apk file. when a button is clicked can I call that apk file?

Comment: It was showing the following error "Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running"

Comment: i look this, perhaps can help you : [Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running? - At Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526565/error-could-not-access-the-package-manager-is-the-system-running-at-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try running it via a gradle task.[image]

Comment: how to run it? Either I have to install debug?

Comment: You can try assemble under build to install.