# Is Xamarin supported to VS2015?

Tags: xamarin

Is Xamarin supported in VS2015?

I get an error every time I execute visual studio using Xamarin.

> Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running? - At Android Studio

Comment: Yes, VS2015 is supported.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Xamarin is supported in VS2015.

On [Visual Studio's own page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/xamarin-vs.aspx), it's even indicated that Xamarin is installed automatically with VS2015:

> Visual Studio 2015 automatically installs the latest version of Xamarin. Choose a Xamarin project to start building your app and use the Visual Studio debugger, IntelliSense, and other powerful features of the Visual Studio IDE.

Also, looking at your post, I guess you experience another issue in which you are not able deploy your applications to an Android emulator?

If so, you could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18171385/2399772) and [this post which have already answered the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21537350/2399772). It seems that you may be trying to install the application prematurely to the emulator being started fully.