# xamarin not loading in emulator - emulator loads but timesout shown in visual studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I have spent lot of time restarting and trying to make this work. I am debugging an Android application and the emulator loads but will timeout. Here is the debug log and build order.

Log:

```
 01-24 10:57:27.409 I/art     ( 2473): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
 01-24 10:57:28.095 W/monodroid( 2473): Using override path: /data/user/0/RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs/files/.__override__
 01-24 10:57:28.096 W/monodroid( 2473): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs/files/.__override__
 01-24 10:57:28.173 W/monodroid( 2473): Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
 01-24 10:57:28.173 W/monodroid( 2473): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
 01-24 10:57:28.173 W/monodroid( 2473): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-2.0.so
 01-24 10:57:28.670 W/monodroid( 2473): Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
 01-24 10:57:28.672 W/monodroid-debug( 2473): Not starting the debugger as the timeout value has been reached; current-time: 1485255448  timeout: 1485255383
```

Build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RaysHotDogs.Core, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  RaysHotDogs.Core -> C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs.Core\bin\Debug\RaysHotDogs.Core.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: RaysHotDogs, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\aboutview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\favoritehotdogfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogdetailview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogmenuview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogrowview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\mainmenu.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\meatloversfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\veggieloversfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
2>C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs\HotDogMenuActivity.cs(22,26,22,40): warning CS0169: The field 'HotDogMenuActivity.hotDogListView' is never used
2>C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs\HotDogMenuActivity.cs(23,30,23,40): warning CS0169: The field 'HotDogMenuActivity.allHotDogs' is never used
2>C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs\HotDogMenuActivity.cs(24,35,24,52): warning CS0649: Field 'HotDogMenuActivity.hotDogDataService' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
2>C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs\HotDogDetailActivity.cs(31,35,31,46): warning CS0169: The field 'HotDogDetailActivity.dataService' is never used
2>  RaysHotDogs -> C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs\bin\Debug\RaysHotDogs.dll
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\aboutview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\favoritehotdogfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogdetailview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogmenuview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogrowview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\mainmenu.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\meatloversfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\veggieloversfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\aboutview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\favoritehotdogfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogdetailview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogmenuview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogrowview.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\mainmenu.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\meatloversfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\veggieloversfragment.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
3>Starting deploy Android_Accelerated_x86 ...
3>Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_x86 ...
3>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Android_Accelerated_x86 -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86
3>emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
3>emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
3>emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
3>Hax is enabled
3>Hax ram_size 0x40000000
3>HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
3>console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
3>Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86 is running.
3>Deploying Android_Accelerated_x86 ...
3>Build started.
3>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 devices 
3>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk 
3>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist64 
3>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi 
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;__XAMARIN_ANDROID_v1_0__;__MOBILE__;__ANDROID__;__ANDROID_1__;__ANDROID_2__;__ANDROID_3__;__ANDROID_4__;__ANDROID_5__;__ANDROID_6__;__ANDROID_7__;__ANDROID_8__;__ANDROID_9__;__ANDROID_10__;__ANDROID_11__;__ANDROID_12__;__ANDROID_13__;__ANDROID_14__;__ANDROID_15__;__ANDROID_16__;__ANDROID_17__;__ANDROID_18__;__ANDROID_19__;__ANDROID_20__;__ANDROID_21__;__ANDROID_22__;__ANDROID_23__ /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs.Core\bin\Debug\RaysHotDogs.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.AppContext.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.Specialized.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Console.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Data.Common.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TraceEvent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.Pipes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.AuthenticationManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Cache.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.HttpListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Mail.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.NameResolution.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Ping.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Sockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Utilities.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebSockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Resources.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Handles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Claims.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.DeriveBytes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.Aes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.ECDiffieHellman.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.ECDsa.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.SecureString.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Thread.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Timer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XPath.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.Xsl.Primitives.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\RaysHotDogs.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:library /utf8output AboutActivity.cs Adapters\HotDogListAdapter.cs Fragments\BaseFragment.cs Fragments\VeggieLoversFragment.cs Fragments\FavoriteHotDogFragment.cs Fragments\MeatLoversFragment.cs HotDogDetailActivity.cs HotDogMenuActivity.cs MainActivity.cs MenuActivity.cs Resources\Resource.Designer.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Utility\ImageHelper.cs "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
3>The field 'HotDogDetailActivity.dataService' is never used
3>Field 'HotDogMenuActivity.hotDogDataService' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
3>The field 'HotDogMenuActivity.hotDogListView' is never used
3>The field 'HotDogMenuActivity.allHotDogs' is never used
3>RaysHotDogs -> C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs\bin\Debug\RaysHotDogs.dll
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\aboutview.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\favoritehotdogfragment.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogdetailview.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogmenuview.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\hotdogrowview.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\mainmenu.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\meatloversfragment.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\veggieloversfragment.xml
3>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" 
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs-Signed-Unaligned.apk "C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs\obj\Debug\android\bin\RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs.apk" androiddebugkey 
3>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2046-06-25) or after any future revocation date.
3>C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Rahul\Development\android-xamarin-from-start-to-store\5-android-xamarin-start-store-exercise-files\Demo 2 - Copy\End\RaysHotDogs\RaysHotDogs\bin\Debug\RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\RaysHotDogs.RaysHotDogs-Signed.apk" 
3>Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
3>
3>Build succeeded.
3>Deploy successfully on Android_Accelerated_x86.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Reformat the grammar, add code highlghting to log output.

Comment: Grammar and code formatting tweaks.

Comment: So what is the issue? Doesn't the emulator appear? Did you try with other emulators instead of the ones included in the Android SDK such as [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)? It normally takes a long time for the emulators provided with the Android SDK to start up. You have to wait for it to start, otherwise you'll get the error you experience as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18171385/2399772).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could not access the package manager. is the system running while installing android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524185/could-not-access-the-package-manager-is-the-system-running-while-installing-and)