# Is it possible to run Espresso UI tests on -no-window emulator?

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my Espresso tests on CI (Jenkins in this case) server. I do not have access to the GUI over here so the approach I have decided on is using -no-window parameter on Android Emulator. Emulator starts fine however I receive `Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?` error during installation process. So as I mentioned above, is there any way that I could run Espresso tests on non-gui machine? I know there is Jenkins plugin for Android Emulator but it seems to be outdated, last update is from 2015 I belive.. thanks!

Comment: This is possible: https://paulemtz.blogspot.de/2013/05/android-testing-in-headless-emulator.html. Emulator must be using software gpu rendering: `-gpu off`

Comment: It doesn't work, same Package Manager error appears

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the running espresso tests on the emulator in the docker container. The problem occurred when I tried to run Activity. 
Instrumental Unit Tests were working.

When I switched from x86_64 image to x86 tests pass. I run emulator using this command:  `emulator -avd Nexus6P -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-window -no-audio -gpu off`

Answer (score 0):

According to the internet (e.g. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524185/could-not-access-the-package-manager-is-the-system-running-while-installing-and)) you will get this error message if the emulator is not fully started or the device is locked.

You can try two things:

- Send unlock keyevent to device (first check if device is online)

  `./adb devices` 
  `./adb shell input keyevent 82`
- Wait until device is fully started

  `./adb shell getprop init.svc.bootanim`
   `// You should get "1" when ready`

I currently have the exact same problem and sadly none of the above solutions is working for me. I guess the best way to  identify the problem is to run the emulator with GUI to see what it is doing but I don't have access to the server.

Let me know if you can solve your problem.

Edit:
Also try to do a sleep for a few minutes (about 10 mins if your server isnt that fast) before calling

`./adb install` or `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`

Edit#2:

My emulator is finally working but had to use x86 images. Still no idea why arm is not working..