# I got Error While running android studio emulator, Session 'apk' installing failed

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, reactjs, redux

> Unknown failure: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
>
> Error while Installing APKs

I got this error when I am running an emulator, I have also restarted my laptop a lot. but I am getting the same error again and again. please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could not access the package manager. is the system running while installing android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524185/could-not-access-the-package-manager-is-the-system-running-while-installing-and)

Comment: basically you need to start the emulator first(are using android studio to build/run app or are you doing it manually?)

Comment: i did this all. but same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the app if it is already present in the emulator and then start the emulator and run it.

Comment: i have uninstall the android studio and reinstalling android studio fixed the issue